# label not found in axis when using tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am in a google colab environment and trying to train a tensorflow decision forest.
I loaded my dataset in like so:`dataset_df = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/Medical_Error_Test_Data-_1_.csv")` 
I proceed to take out NaN values:
`labels =dataset_df.keys()  for label in labels: dataset_df[label] = dataset_df[label].fillna(0)`
I then convert all the labels to integers:
`for label in labels: classes.append(dataset_df[label].unique().tolist()) print(f"Label classes: {classes}") for classs,label in zip(classes,labels): dataset_df[label] = dataset_df[label].map(classs.index)`
where classes starts as an empty list

I then split my data set into train and test:
`def split_dataset(dataset, test_ratio=0.30):
"""Splits a panda dataframe in two."""
test_indices = np.random.rand(len(dataset)) < test_ratio
return dataset[~test_indices], dataset[test_indices]

train_ds_pd, test_ds_pd = split_dataset(dataset_df)`

Finally I try and convert it to a tf dataset:
`train_ds = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(train_ds_pd, label=label)` 
Here label is 'Sub System' which when I print a list of keys of train_ds does show up. When I try to use it as a label though I get this error : KeyError: "['Sub System'] not found in axis"
I have tried all other labels in the key set and they all give this error.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

I tried to turn my dataframe into a dataset and i get an error

Comment: Please make sure to not split your code up into 20 tiny fragmenst. even though your explanations are nice it would be better to have the code better readable and the comments as #comment inside the code. Additionaly there are some code parts not formated correctly in your post. All in all i dont think anyone is going thrue the effort of decripting this. So please feel free to edit your question to make it look better.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. It is fixed by renaming the column, so that there are no spaces in there. tensorflow datasets semi-automatically replace spaces by "_", but it somehow breaks on declaring label. So just rename your label column so that it does not have spaces

```py
YourDataFrame.rename(columns = {"your label": "my_label"}, inplace=True)

smth = tfdf.keras.pd_dataframe_to_tf_dataset(YourDataFrame, label='my_label')
```